# UITableView Setting some cells as "unselectable"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I set the UITableView's cell property to be unselectable? I don't want to see that blue selection box when the user taps on the cell.

Comment: Note recent googlers: The way to do this as of iOS 6 and greater is `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` as [noted by Ayush below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18086967/90413)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Set the table cell's `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.  That should prevent it from highlighting, and you can also check that property in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Kendall is right.  Follow Sebastian Celis' answer to prevent didSelectRowAtIndexPath from being called in the first place.  You should also set selectionStyle, though, to prevent the highlighting.

Comment: yeah i suppose the Sebastian Celis' answer to be the correct answer, thanks Daniel

Comment: Storyboard fans using static TableViews can select a UITableViewCell and under Attributes Inspector can find the *Selection* Field and set it to *None*

Answer (score 204):

### To Prevent Row Selection

To completely prevent selection of the `UITableViewCell`, have your `UITableViewDelegate` implement [`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:). From that method you can return `nil` if you do not want the row to be selected.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    // Determine if row is selectable based on the NSIndexPath.

    if (rowIsSelectable) {
        return path;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This prevents the row from being selected and [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) from being called. Note, however, that this does *not* prevent the row from being highlighted.

### To Prevent Row Highlighting

If you would like to prevent the row from being visually highlighted on touch, you can ensure that the cell's [`selectionStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectionStyle) is set to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, or preferably you can have your `UITableViewDelegate` implement [`tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:) as follows:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tv shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Determine if row is selectable based on the NSIndexPath.

    return rowIsSelectable;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. It actually fixes the problem instead of masking it.

Comment: Note that tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: is called after highlighting the cell, which will produce a flicker. From Apple's description: _This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their finger; the row isn't selected until then, although it is highlighted on touch-down._

Comment: I agree with @simpleBob. In order to use this solution, you need to also set cell.selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone on the unselectable rows. Otherwise it looks tacky.

Comment: Then the best answer is still the accepted answer. You can just choose to do nothing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` because `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` will always be called anyway.

Comment: worked great for me. for rowIsSelectable, i just did UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (cell.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone)

Answer (score 17):

use this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: That only stops the selection color from showing, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is still called.

Comment: This is also exactly the same answer as Daniel Dickison's to this question.

Comment: Swift 2.2 UPDATE -- cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

Answer (score 11):

For iOS 6+ only.

You can implement the method 
`tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` in your delegate.
Read more here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Should have far more up votes. This is the correct answer, changing selection style so you can't see a cell is selected, disabling userinteraction so you can't tap on a cell or deselecting cells on selection are hacks.

Answer (score 9):

Had this problem, too, tried everything already mentioned. The final trick, which got rid of the "blue flash" at selecting a table cell was adding this line:

```
self.myTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Not sure whether it was this one line or everything combined, but as total grand result I get no more blue selection or even the blue flash. Happy!

Comment: Problem with this is that it makes it so all cells in the tableview are not selectable. If you want some cell to be selectable, and others to not be selectable, this won't do it. Sebastian's approach worked for me.

Comment: True, allowsSelection = NO will disable selection for all cells.

Comment: Is there an equivalent property in Interface Builder for this property?

Answer (score 8):

Set `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Comment: Wait, do it like that.  Sort of.  make 'FALSE' lower case and lose that crazy semicolon.  That will swift it for you. ' FALSE' was evil and wrong, now 'NO' is evil and wrong.  Until next week when 'false'  is evil and wrong do it that way.

Answer (score 6):

using IB is also an elegant way:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apple says that the first thing you should do in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is to deselect the row

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```

Then you can change the AccessoryType to be a checkmark, or none, etc. So when you enter didSelectRowAtIndexPath you could deselect the row, and if its not meant to be selected, simply don't check that row.

[Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9)

Comment: In that case, when a user touches the cell, it will be highlighted for a short time and then unhighlighted - but as I understand, the point is to completely stop it from highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to add a couple category methods to `UITableViewCell`. I like this better than Sebastians (also good) answer because the way I'm building my table. I thought it might be helpful to someone else.

```
- (void)setSelectable:(BOOL)enabled {
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:enabled];
}

- (BOOL)isSelectable {
    BOOL disabled = [self selectionStyle]==UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone &&
                     [self isUserInteractionEnabled];
    return ! disabled;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4:** 
You can prevent selection and highlighting by using the UITableViewDelegate: **shouldHighlightRowAt** 

*This answer assumes you have a custom cell created named: **CustomTableViewCell**

 And that you created a boolean inside that custom cell named: **isSelectable***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    if cell.isSelectable == false {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

This is the Swift version of Sebastian Celis's objc answer.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have designed your cell in Interface Builder, you can do this by removing the checkbox from '**User Interaction Enabled**' for the `tableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way to avoid the selection appearing as blue.

Select a cell you don't want to appear as blue.

Then select the attributes inspector (the shield icon next to the ruler icon on the properties view on the side).

Then change the 'Selection' field from 'Blue' to 'None'.

Note, presumably this is still selecting, it will just not appear as selected if all you want is to avoid the UI effect.

Answer (score 0):

To make certain row unselected you have to make some changes in two methods of UITableView delegate.

In the method below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

after allocation of the cell, write the code below

```
if(indexPath.row == someCellNumber) cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

The above code will prevent highlighting the cell, if somehow user tries to selects.

in this delegate method below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if(indexPath.row == someCellNumber) return;

    //for other cells write the code below...
}
```

if you don't write `if(indexPath.row == someCellNumber) return;` row will still be selected and there is a chance of app crash

Answer (score 0):

Use tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath: instead of tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to get rid of the flash that appears first time you touch the cell.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

In the cell class:

```
selectionStyle = .none
```