# How to make a cell on a UITableView not selectable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a cell that I am inserting to the top of a UITableView. How can I make sure that when the user clicks on the cell, it doesn't show the blue selected indicator?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

To remove the ability of selecting any table cells, or particular table cells based on the row index, use `willSelectRowAt`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {


        return nil
    }
```

To simply remove the UI effect of selecting the element, set the [selection style of the UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle) to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

Swift 5:

```
selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: This doesn't make the cell non-selectable it just means the visual appearance of the cell doesn't change when it is selected. `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` still gets called when the cell is tapped. To actually prevent selection you need to [implement tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/812921/172218) on your `UITableViewDelegate` and return nil for non-selectable rows.

Comment: Swift 3 - `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none`

Comment: Or simply: `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Answer (score 65):

To make a cell completely non-selectable on a per-cell basis two things are required:

1- As others said:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

2- Implement this delegate method as follows:

```
// Called before the user changes the selection. Return a new indexPath, or nil, to change the proposed selection.
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone){
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

From the Storyboard set the following for the Table View:

**Selection**: No Selection

**Show Selection On Touch**: False

[image]

Answer (score 13):

you can do

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: One dot is missing. Here is the fixed version: cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

Answer (score 6):

for Swift 3 you can use

```
 cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: just past that code into cellForRowAt indexPath method of table view , its simple

Comment: this method is useful when u want to user interaction disable on table view otherwise you can use method share by Mr Ben Below

Comment: Works in Swift 4 also.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Should be the correct answer. Another way is that in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, detect cell index and just do nothing and return.

Comment: My favorite part about this answer is that you can declare it INSIDE the cell. If you have a cell (like an empty state cell) that you never want to respond to taps, this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift Syntax:**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Answer (score 5):

I am answering from point of view of disabling TableViewCell.
You can use the storyboard.

`XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)`

Select the TableVewCell on storyboard and following will be visible on the right side panel - Utilities.

[image: Utilities Sidebar]

Make the **Selection: None**

That's all!

Answer (score 5):

The question was how to make certain cells selectable and others not. This was my solution, (after trying lots of other suggestions):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2) {
        return indexPath
    }
    return nil        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myTable.allowsSelection = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Update in Swift 3:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement this [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614988-tableview) of `UITableViewDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: As suggested Above 
"This doesn't make the cell non-selectable it just means the visual appearance of the cell doesn't change when it is selected. tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: still gets called when the cell is tapped. To actually prevent selection you need to implement tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: on your UITableViewDelegate and return nil for non-selectable rows. –"

Comment: @Siyavash as indicated in the original question, this person only wants to hide "the blue selected indicator". That is not the same as wanting to make it completely non-selectable. Simply put the person asking the question is only trying to hide visual indication of a selection.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell;
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5

you may wanna try this too

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ability of selecting **any table cells**, use willSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return nil
}
```

or by definition during table initialization (if you are not in table editing mode):

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

if you need to restrict any table cells selection during table editing:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
```

To remove the ability of selecting **the top cell** use the same function but with statement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

To simply remove **the UI effect of selecting** the element, set the selection style of the UITableViewCell to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Swift 5:

```
selectionStyle = .none
```