# How to do a modal UITableView row?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In Mail after dragging an email to the left, More and Trash appear. This row becomes modal. A tap on anywhere else in the table view is only used to close the email's menu.

How do I do this in my own application?

Comment: I think this will answer your question;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641530/how-to-make-a-cell-on-a-uitableview-not-selectable

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699431/uitableviewcell-custom-editingaccessoryview-not-properly-dismissed I'm sure last time I looked at this, you get it for free with standard editing accessories? Are you using a table view controller or a table view in a standard VC?

Comment: How about this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

Comment: I'm just going to close this. At this point, it's easy to do in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was asked prior to iOS 8. In iOS 8 and later, you can just implement [tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:);