# Can you make TableViewCells not be able to be Selected?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am currently working with TableViewCells in xCode and I am wondering if there is a way to make the cell not be highlighted/selected whenever it is tapped on. The answer can be either in code or by using the Interface Builder.

If I am not being specific enough or if you are confused as of what I am asking, please let me know and I will clarify. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190908/how-can-i-disable-the-uitableview-selection-highlighting?rq=1

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641530/how-to-make-a-cell-on-a-uitableview-not-selectable/17607210?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question, especially the comment on the accepted answer

Comment: If you want to keep the cell clickable and only not animate when being clicked, use `cell.selectionStyle = .none` inside `cellForRow` method.

Comment: **cell.selectionStyle = .none**

Comment: Thank you, and I did not see this question already answered during my search so I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off all selection in the UITableView by setting [allowsSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614911-allowsselection) to false.

If you want to do it on individual cells, set the cell [SelectionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623221-selectionstyle) to `.none` and `userInteractionEnabled` to `false`