# UITableView No Data Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My UITableView get data off the internet. Sometimes it doesn't receive any (cell) data. It just shows a blank table.

How can I show a message/cell to the user that no data records have been found?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to return one cell reporting on the lack of data.

If you're keeping your cell data in an array that's a class property (let's say `NSArray *listings`), you can go:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.listings count] == 0) {
         return 1; // a single cell to report no data
    }
    return [self.listings count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.listings count] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No records to display";
        //whatever else to configure your one cell you're going to return
        return cell;
    }

    // go on about your business, you have listings to display
}
```

Comment: is it a good idea to cache this cell like with other regular cells? if so, how do you do that?

Comment: You don't have to worry about caching this single cell because it's going to go away the minute you have actual data to show, and the autorelease will take care of its memory for you. It'll never scroll off the table, so there's really nothing to cache.

By the way, you want to do this AS YOU LOAD your data, too. Then when your network process is done and you've filled your data source, call `reloadData` on your UITableView.

Comment: works like a charm - just had to adjust the font a bit to get the message I wanted to fit:  [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@Helvetica-Bold" size:13]];

Comment: Also typically in this scenario you are going to want to make this cell not selectable, or your app with throw a bad exec likely unless you're handling it some other way.  Set the selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone - http://stackoverflow.com/a/812969/962904

Comment: But, this approach will break the app if we are using insertRowsAtIndexPaths or deleteRowsAtIndexPaths rows methods. Adding the first ou deleting the last cell will cause a error, because the method numberOfRowsInSection return 1, but the data source array is empty.

Comment: @Warthog - UITableView only knows about what's in the data source array by way of what its `dataSource` delegate tells it. Which is why you fudge the `numberOfRowsInSection` to always answer 1 even if the real answer is 0. Go ahead and delete the last item from the source array; we'll claim there's 1 row, then populate it empty, just like we should.

Comment: I suggest using table header for this purpose.  This seems like a hack.  If you follow this, you will need to sprinkle the code all over to handle the special case of "one" row - e.g. selection, deletion, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a test in your -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: implementation and display a special UITableViewCell saying "no results available" when you get no data.

Another approach, which generally looks better, is to add a custom view to the UITableView directly. Don't forget to remove it when there are results to display.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a UILabel to your view
This can be created programmatically or in your xib.  If your xib contains a UITableView as [self view], as is typical for a UITableViewController, then create a property for the label on your viewController

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel       *noResultsLabel;
```

Drag a UILabel from the library into the document window as a sibling to your "Table View".
Set text properties (36pt bold font, light gray looks pretty good)
Control drag from "File's Owner" to wire the outlet to the label.

[image: UITableView with no results UILabel]

In your server callback, you can add the label to the view.  Here's an example:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Server callbacks
- (void)serviceExecutionComplete:(NSMutableArray *)results {
    [self setServerData:results];
    if ([results count] == 0)
    {
        // no results,
        CGRect viewFrame = [[self view] frame];
        [[self noResultsLabel] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, (viewFrame.size.height - 100) / 2, viewFrame.size.width, 50.0)];
        [[self view] addSubview:[self noResultsLabel]];
    }
    else
    {
            [[self noResultsLabel] removeFromSuperview];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

You could do the same thing in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: if that fits your design better

Answer (score 1):

I was contemplating showing an `emptyDataView` in either header/footer, or hacking one of the row like the suggested answer from Dan.

But I think the cleanest is to create a view outside the tableView.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *emptyDataView;
```

Then hide/show the view in `numberOfRowsInSection:` like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    // Show empty data view if no data
    _emptyDataView.hidden = ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0) ? NO : YES;

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

This works well with Core Data NSFetchedResultsController and hide the view once there is data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the below link it is easy if we create a label and set that as the background view for UITableView like below. May be it is useful for someone. http://www.appcoda.com/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-empty/

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (data) {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        return 1;

    } else {

        // Display a message when the table is empty
        UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

        messageLabel.text = @"No data is currently available. Please pull down to refresh.";
        messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:20];
        [messageLabel sizeToFit];

        self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach. Be warned that if you return 0 sections when you have no data, the app crashes if you use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.  To remedy this, I always return 1 for the number of sections.   I also added `self.tableView.backgroundView = nil` if data exists.

Answer (score -1):

Here i use code like:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
if ([jsonArray count] != 0){
    tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    numOfSections                 = 1;
    tableview.backgroundView   = nil;
}
else{
    UILabel *noDataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableview.bounds.size.width, tableview.bounds.size.height)];
    noDataLabel.text             = @"No item found.";
    noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
    noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tableview.backgroundView     = noDataLabel;
    tableview.separatorStyle     = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
  return numOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [jsonArray count ];
}
```