# Thumb Nail Gallery?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi am curious how I would go about implementing a view like (See below) Similar to the one used for the iPhone photo application. My initial idea was a table view with each cell holding 4 images, can anyone point me in the right direction. I am particularly interesting in using APIs from Apple so not too bothered about 3rd party APIs / Controllers at this stage.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yup, as you say, a table view would work, with each of the 4 things (/row) being an UIButton with a custom image. You have to make sure that the table row itself isn't selectable though. ([UITableView Setting some cells as "unselectable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812426/uitableview-setting-some-cells-as-unselectable))  Make sure to use table view cell caching if you're going to have a lot of rows.

The actual table view cell could be a UITableViewCell subclass or just the normal one, with some subviews added to its contentView.

Comment: Actually, after reading I noticed that you didn't mention that you wanted the images to be "tappable". If you do, use UIButtons, and if you don't, use UIImage (which you could attach a tap gesture recogniser to, but that might be overkill)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Apple provides classes to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Three20 API](http://three20.info/). This is the API used to build the Facebook iPhone app and has a very very large collection of UI elements, including many photo management UIs.

The thumbnail viewer looks like (from their site):

[image]

Comment: Normally this would be a good answer but when he/she specifically asked not for a 3rd party solution or APIs...

Comment: I read "not too bothered about 3rd party APIs / Controllers at this stage." as him not minding having 3rd party APIs suggested. But further analysis of the confusing statement suggests you may be correct. :P Oh well, might help other people in the future to know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS, this work is mostly done for you.  Check Apple's docs for `MPMediaPickerController`.

Comment: I had a look at the docs, but it doesn't seem to be able to present your own custom images (and if it did, it seems strage that three20 would implement it) (and I'm not sure if the OP wanted to use custom images or not)

Answer (score 0):

[AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) is FOSS and is used in many high profile applications like the Kobo reader and Netflix Actors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UIScrollView and with a bunch of UIImageViews or UIButtons(with image as background image). this code uses Buttons on scroll view. Also u wud need a function to generate thumbnails, unless ur using the asset library in which case the function is already there.

```
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (items*itemWidth)];

    for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {

        if (i % 4 == 0) {

            y+=1;
            x = 0;
        }


        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[items objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGRect rect2 = myButton.frame;
        rect2.size.height = kScrollObjHeight2;
        rect2.size.width = kScrollObjWidth2;
        rect2.origin.y = 10 + (y * 70) + (y *5);
        rect2.origin.x = 8 + (x * kScrollObjWidth2) + (x *8);
        myButton.frame = rect2;
        myButton.tag = i;   // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        x = x + 1;


        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];


        [scrollview addSubview:myButton];

    }

};


[scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollview setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollview.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;     // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;

scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
```